# Override default mailer URL in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, gmail, swiftmailer

I am trying to give the possibility to users to send emails to me in Symfony, I could send emails to my self but I am not able to get emails from other emails because the default email adress given in the .env file is not getten override.

```
  /**
 * @Route("/send_msg", name="send_msg", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function index(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{

  $name =  $request->query->get('name');
  $mail =  $request->query->get('mail');
  $msg =  $request->query->get('msg');


    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Client'))
        ->setFrom($mail)
        ->setTo('my_gmail@gmail.com')
        ->setBody($msg)

    ;

    $mailer->send($message);
    return new JsonResponse();

}
```

and this is the .env file

```
###> symfony/mailer ###
# MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost
###< symfony/mailer ###

 # For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://username:password@localhost"
 # For a generic SMTP server, use: "smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode="
 # Delivery is disabled by default via "null://localhost"
  MAILER_URL=gmail://my_gmail@gmail.com:my_pass@localhost
 ###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###

    ###> symfony/sendgrid-mailer ###
    #MAILER_DSN=sendgrid://KEY@default
    ###< symfony/sendgrid-mailer ###
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using your Gmail credentials as SMTP server. You can't and shouldn't send from any other email address through your Gmail credentials. Even if you were using another SMTP server that allows any From address, you shouldn't use an email address that's not authenticated in your SMTP service as the From address, because your email would probably never see the light of an inbox.

An option would be to set the Reply-To address to your user's email address by using `$message->setReplyTo($mail);`. That way if you hit the reply button in your mailbox, the mail should be addressed to the user's email address.

Comment: but I want to receive emails from others not to send or reply to them.. it's not what I want

Comment: Use setReply it seems so, then when you click the answer button, you will answer who needs

Comment: @AsMaBoudjemaa As I said, it is technically possible to use any email address as the From address. But you'd have to use another SMTP service than Gmail. Gmail doesn't allow you to send from any other email address than your own Gmail address. But still if you would use another SMTP service, chances are that these mails will be discarded as spam because you're not authorized to use your user's email addresses as From address. That's why I suggested using Reply-To, even though it's not exactly want you wanted, it's the best alternative in my opinion.

Comment: @user1026090 that's what I did thank you for your advice and help